# Using autofac to inject properties into asp.net pages: Overriding PropertyInjectionModule behaviour to inject values/settings

Tags: asp.net, autofac

Is it possible to inject values/settings into ASP.NET Pages via autofac's PropertyInjectionModule?  I get the impression that default handler behavior is to search for properties and find any types that match services in the container.

eg for a page:

```
public class MyPage: System.Web.UI.Page {
    public IDataProvider DataProvider { get; set; }

    public bool SomeSetting {get; set; }
    public bool AnotherSetting { get; set; }
    public string MySettings { get; set; }

    // stuff
}
```

I thought maybe you could specify properties:

```
builder.RegisterType<MyPage>()
    .WithProperty("SomeSetting", true)
    .WithProperty("AnotherSetting", false)
    .WithProperty("MySettings", "do-re-mi");
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I realise I could setup an IMyPageConfig interface and provide settings that way but these are optional properties that may or may not need to be set.

Comment: Are you using the [Autofac ASP.NET Integration](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/AspNetIntegration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IoC in ASP.NET `Page`s is a bit limited - although the module is injecting properties into the page, it can't really use Autofac's regular dependency injection features.

In WebForms the way people typically get around this is to use something like Model-View-Presenter, where the page is just a 'dumb' view and the presenter is where the logic (and proper dependency injection) takes place.

Check out http://webformsmvp.com/ - I think there is an IoC example and Autofac support available there.